# Write a statement to display the day from the regular expression match in result. Note: The given date is in month, day, year order

Tags: javascript, regex

I may just be up too late, but I can't get this one figured out.

**Write a statement to display the day from the regular expression match in result. Note: The given date is in month, day, year order.**

```
var re = /(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/;
var date = "4/15/91"; // Code will also be tested with value "11/2/2015"
var result = re.exec(date);

console.log(/\d{2}/.exec(date));
```

[Screenshot of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTqz0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the whole match + 3 capture groups, just take the 2nd capture group (3rd item, index 2) from the `result` array:

```js
var re = /(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/;
var date = "4/15/91"; // Code will also be tested with value "11/2/2015"
var result = re.exec(date);

console.log(result[2]);
```

Answer (score -1):

re.exec returns the full array at index[0], so in order to parse any expression, the first result will be at [1] and so on

Since date is the second grouping, the array will store it at index 2

console.log(result[2])

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it